# Yocto recipe for pydantic module

Tags: python-3.x, yocto, pydantic

I try to include python modul pydantic from pypi.org with next recipe (generated auto by https://github.com/NFJones/pipoe ) in Yocto 2.6 Thud

```
SUMMARY = "Data validation and settings management using python 3.6 type hinting"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic"
AUTHOR = "Samuel Colvin <s@muelcolvin.com>"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=2c02ea30650b91528657db64baea1757"

inherit setuptools3

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/d2/12a808613937a6b98cd50d6467352f01322dc0d8ca9fb5b94441625d6684/pydantic-1.8.2.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "7845d2f3c8fe8602f73f53ec5b6dfa29"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "26464e57ccaafe72b7ad156fdaa4e9b9ef051f69e175dbbb463283000c05ab7b"

S = "${WORKDIR}/pydantic-1.8.2"

DEPENDS += " "
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3-typing-extensions"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

Depended module is also included with generated recipe and it's compiled OK.
Anyway I've receive error during bitbake and can't avoid it:

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
|   File "setup.py", line 47
|     self.links.add(f'.. _#{id}: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/{id}')
|                                                                                     ^
| SyntaxError: invalid syntax
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Any ideas (without forge and edit the source) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python3` recipe in Yocto 2.6 Thud, is version Python 3.5.6.

However, `pydantic` PyPI package uses Python [`f-strings`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.5.6.bb?h=thud) in its setup.py, which is syntax introduced in Python 3.6. Therefore, the recipe fails to build because Yocto's Python 3.5 does not recognise that syntax, hence the `SyntaxError` from the Python interpreter trying to run `setup.py`.

The `pydantic` [install guide](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/install/) says:

> pydantic has no required dependencies except python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, or 3.9, typing-extensions, and the dataclasses backport package for python 3.6. If you've got python 3.6+ and pip installed, you're good to go.

To build this package within Yocto, you'll need a release that includes a newer version of Python 3 - which is typically updated in Yocto's minor point releases. See below:

| Yocto Release | Version of `python3` recipe |
| --- | --- |
| thud (2.6) | 3.5.6 ([source](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.5.6.bb?h=thud)), **not supported by `pydantic`** |
| warrior (2.7) | 3.7.7 ([source](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.7.7.bb?h=warrior)) |
| zeus (3.0) | 3.7.8 ([source](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.7.8.bb?h=zeus)) |
| dunfell (3.1) | 3.8.11 |
| gatesgarth (3.2) | 3.8.5 |
| hardknott (3.3) | 3.9.5 |

Comment: I know error comming from f-format in Python but thought in Thud is at least Python 3.6.x
Will try to upgrade to Warrior but I'm afraid that could lead to bigger mess...
Thanks for response @Justin